# Problema com System.IndexOutOfRangeException no C#

Tags: c#, array, .net, outofrange

Preciso criar uma classe `Marca` e uma `Modelo`, ambos relacionados à carros, onde modelo saberá sua marca e marca deverá conhecer seus modelos.

Classe Modelo:

```
namespace AssocMatrizes.Model
{
    class Modelo
    {
        public string Nome { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Classe Marca:

```
namespace AssocMatrizes.Model
{
    class Marca
    {
        private int quantidadeModelos = 0;

        public string Nome { get; set; }

        public Modelo[] Modelos { get; set; }

        public Marca(int maxModelos)
        {
            Modelos = new Modelo[maxModelos];
        }

        public void RegistrarModelo(Modelo modelo)
        {
            Modelos[quantidadeModelos++] = modelo;
        }
    }
}
```

Programa Principal:

```
namespace AssocMatrizes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int opcao;
            int quantidade = 0;
            Modelo modelo = new Modelo();

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[1]- Adicionar");
                Console.WriteLine("[2]- Sair");
                opcao = Int16.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (opcao)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Marca marca = new Marca(quantidade);
                        Console.WriteLine("Marca: ");
                        marca.Nome = Console.ReadLine();

                        Console.WriteLine("Modelo: ");
                        modelo.Nome = Console.ReadLine();

                        marca.RegistrarModelo(modelo);
                        quantidade++;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            } while (opcao != 2);

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Quando eu vou rodar o programa, ele aparece o seguinte problema após eu entrar com dados no console.

[image: Erro mostrado]

Já tentei várias coisas e não achei a solução para o meu problema, pelo que percebo é algo com a passagem pra função ou o *array*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este problema específico é que está acessando um elemento do *array* que não existe, está acessando um número maior que a quantidade elementos criados, e precisa validar isto. Seria algo assim:

```
public void RegistrarModelo(Modelo modelo) => if(quantidadeModelos >= Modelos.Lenght) Modelos[quantidadeModelos++] = modelo;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Array/OutOfRange.cs).

Pode ser que prefira fazer alguma coisa se não for possível fazer a adição do modelo. Uma solução comum é retornar um booleano se deu certo ou não para o código consumidor saber se conseguir realizar a operação.

Existem outros erros conceituais neste código, mas nem vou entrar nisso (por exemplo isso `new Marca(quantidade);` na forma usada não parece fazer sentido, mas só quem fez pode garantir). Tem um de mecanismo que vai quebrar sua aplicação e [já falei em diversas perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A101%20tryparse). Ao problema relatado a resposta está dada e a sugestão de rever tudo o que está fazendo e como está aprendendo também.

Programar é entender tudo o que está fazendo, principalmente entender os mecanismos que está usando. Não use nada que não domine por completo o que aquilo faz, tudo o que pode acontecer, como resolver cada problema, tem que estudar cada mínimo detalhe daquilo antes de usar, porque se não fizer isso está criando códigos aleatórios que podem funcionar por coincidência, e isto é o pior que pode lhe acontecer, já que se der erro você sabe que tem algo errado que alguém vai corrigir pra você na internet, mas se não der erro ainda pode estar errado e você não poderá fazer nada porque não entende o que está fazendo.